# program shows unresolved external symbols on every line of opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I want to make an augmented reality application .. So i built the opencv 2.4.6 source with the opengl and at libraries using cmake .. then included its libraries and headers in visual studio .. 
I have written a simple program to make an opencv window with opengl support ..

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);


CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
IplImage* frame;
IplImage* image;
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

namedWindow("Mywin", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

but the problem is .. it shows unresolved external symbol for all the opencv codes .. example of one of the errors is

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvQueryFrame referenced in function _main`

Answer (score 1):

That error means you have not told visual studio that it needs to link against the right libraries. I'd go back to the instructions on setting up windows ([here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to)) and double check all your paths are correct + that the libraries you built all built correctly.